# Undefined variable en fecha (string to date) en PHP / Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on null

Tags: php, sql

Tengo el siguiente código PHP

```
<?php
    include("database/db.php");
        
    if(isset($_POST['consultar'])){
                
        if(!empty($_POST['credito'])){
            $credito_query = $_POST['credito'];
 
            $tsql_comentarios = "SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE num_credito = $credito_query";

            $query_comentarios = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql_comentarios);
                    
            $row_comentarios = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query_comentarios);

            if($row_comentarios > 0){
                $fecha = $row_comentarios['fecha'];
                $resultado = $row_comentarios['resultado'];
                $comentario = $row_comentarios['comentario'];
                $agente_ejecutivo = $row_comentarios['agente_ejecutivo'];
            }

        }
    }
?>
```

Genera una consulta a BD, muestra la fecha correctamente solo si inserto una cuenta a consultar

```
<th scope="row"><?php print $row_comentarios['fecha']->format('d/m/Y');?></th>
```

Pero si no, muestra los errores de:

Undefined variable, obviamente no muestra la fecha por que la variable no esta definida.
Uncaught Error: Call to a member function format() on null, este si no se que signifique.

En Undefined cuando es un simple print se puede corregir con:

```
<?php print isset($nombre_variable) ? $nombre_variable : ""?>
```

Con ello si la variable esta indefinida, no la muestra o la marca como un null valido pero no marca la "NOTICE"

Pero como verán en la tag

```
<th scope="row"><?php print $row_comentarios['fecha']->format('d/m/Y');?></th>
```

Quiero hacer print a un date ¿Cómo le hago para que no marque ni notice ni Uncaught Error si no inserto una cuenta a consultar?

Pensé que era con un isset igual que en la explicación de arriba o talvez si pero... ¿Cómo lo codifico?

Comment: Todos los valores que recibes de una consulta a base de datos, por defecto, son cadena, entonces no está disponible el método `->format()`, tendrías que convertir a objeto de fecha y, solo entonces, [formatear](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.format.php)

Comment: ¿Lo dices por el "Uncaught Error"? Es decir ya puedo mostrar la consulta de String a Date pero solo si coloco una cuenta a consultar, si no... me marcar la notice de variable no definida, necesito que no marque esa notice si no inserto una cuenta a consultar, supongo que lo de formateo queda con $row_comentarios['fecha']->format('d/m/Y')

Comment: @MinorMX ¿y si no tienes una fecha a mostrar entonces que debe mostrar?

Comment: No la tiene porque dentro del form no ah consultado nada en la BD, por eso marca Variable Indefinida, si hiciera la consulta ingresando la cuenta mostraria la fecha porque asi en $fecha guardo el String de fecha desde BD

Comment: Me parece muy raro que puedas mostrar algo con ese código, porque, de entrada, no tienes definida la variable `$row`, que no puede ser mayor que cero y, por tanto, no debería pasar la comprobación. Y, debo insistir, una cadena no dispone del método `->format()`.

Comment: Ah perdoname, esa parte del $row le falta el "_comentarios", pero sí, si muestra información por esa parte no te preocupes, lo del -> format, se supone es para "String to Date" y si hace su función

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del condicional

```
if($row_comentarios > 0){
    $fecha = $row_comentarios['fecha'];
    $resultado = $row_comentarios['resultado'];
    $comentario = $row_comentarios['comentario'];
    $agente_ejecutivo = $row_comentarios['agente_ejecutivo'];
}
```

Pasa de String a Date de una vez en la declaracion de la variable

```
$fecha = $row_comentarios['fecha']->format('d/m/Y');
```

En el print en la tabla, coloque lo siguiente

```
<th scope="row"><?php print isset($fecha) ? $fecha : "" ?></th>
```

Hasta el momento me funciona, espero no me genera algún tipo de código espagueti